# 502 Bad Gateway Ingress nginx with kibana

Tags: nginx, kibana, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to deploy kibana on a kubernetes cluster. I can port-forward locally and I can access kibana without any problems but when I apply the ingress yaml it gives me a 502 Bad Gateway. What am I missing here?

This is my ingress yaml:

```yaml
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: quickstart
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: kibana.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: quickstart-kb-http 
              port:
                number: 5601
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - kibana.mydomain.com
    secretName: mydomain-secret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.55.55.55
```

The logs from Ingress:

```bash
2023/03/07 10:19:56 [error] 11977#11977: *278798777 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.41.41.41, server: kibana.mydomain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.2.2.4:5601/favicon.ico", host: "kibana.mydomain.com", referrer: "https://kibana.mydomain.com/"
2023/03/07 10:19:56 [error] 11977#11977: *278798777 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.41.41.41, server: kibana.mydomain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.2.2.4:5601/favicon.ico", host: "kibana.mydomain.com", referrer: "https://kibana.mydomain.com/" 10.41.41.41 - - [07/Mar/2023:10:19:56 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 502 552 "https://kibana.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 146 0.018 [quickstart-quickstart-kb-http-5601] [] 172.2.2.4:5601, 172.2.2.4:5601, 172.2.2.4:5601 0, 0, 0 0.012, 0.004, 0.004 502, 502, 502 81a10e31ca6778cbfd738bae3195dabf
```

My running service:

```bash
DESKTOP:~$ kubectl get services quickstart-kb-http -n quickstart
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
quickstart-kb-http   ClusterIP   172.2.2.4   <none>        5601/TCP   1d1h
```

My pod:

```bash
DESKTOP:~$ kubectl get pod quickstart-kb-5261adb64f-wtq41 -n quickstart
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
quickstart-kb-5261adb64f-wtq41   1/1     Running   0          20h
```

My port forward locally works fine:

```bash
kubectl port-forward quickstart-kb-5261adb64f-wtq41 5601:5601
```

https://kibana.mydomain.com gets 502 Bad Gateway. My certificates are working, they are accepted and the browser says is valid, secrets look like are all working, but I can't reach kibana through ingress
My openssl version is `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)`

Thank you in advance for your advice

Edit:
Adding the ingress

```
@DESKTOP:~$ kubectl get ingress -n quickstart
NAME     CLASS   HOSTS                ADDRESS         PORTS     
kibana   nginx   kibana.mydomain.com   10.55.55.55   80, 443
```

Comment: Ingress resource is created in `quickstart` namespace, are the services and pods in the same (quickstart) namespace?

Comment: Yes, it's running in the same namespace

Comment: Did you verify the service by running `curl` etc? or port forward to service - `kubectl port-forward service/quickstart-kb-http 5601:5601`

Comment: Also looks good `{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2023-03-07T19:26:50Z","tags":[],"pid":2,"method":"post","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/api/telemetry/report [...]` Also in the browser I can go on localhost:5601

Comment: I see the request are sent using HTTP/2.0
can you please redo the check by enforcing http2 in curl?
should be a parameter to your `curl` command `--http2-prior-knowledge`
in case this is the problem, I think there is an ingress configuration to disable the behaviour.